# Minimization of an expression through K-map, in which there are more chances of errors and with Quine-McCluskey Method there are less chance of errors

Tags: boolean-algebra

Minimization of any expression of **4 variables** through K-map, in which there are **more chances of errors** (like error in grouping) and the **same expression** with Quine-McCluskey Method there are **less chance of errors** *but it should be of 4 variables*. And I know that  Quine-McCluskey Method gives accurate result as compare to K-map, when the number of variables exceed from 4 but what about 4 variables?

Comment: (Depending on training, it is quite unlikely to make an error when minimising a single boolean function/expression/circuit in just 4 variables. I fail to see any application in the last decades.) What question do you want answered when  asking `what about 4 variables?` Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Nobody runs these methods by hand any more, so there is zero chance of error. Your study materials are outdated.